# Register User can post video

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I have a blog. I need to add a functionality.
Where Registered user can upload video and Registered user can view all video and Onclick on Particular video That video display and User can comment on video and total view. 
Is there any plugin that provide this functionality.
or Any demo link or code.

Comment: Close-voted as *not a real question*. Everything you describe can be handled by WordPress **out of the box**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either create a custom post type, or a category (depends how you wanna organize it...custom post type would be my goto) to store the videos.  With that in place, you can setup a form in your frontend, making it only visible to registered users, where they can do their video uploading (this functionality is covered elsewhere, so I won't talk about how to do that, if you need docs, `wp_insert_post()` is a good place to start).

You'll also need a way of viewing the videos. The archive of a category or custom post type would work well, as would a custom page template...that's sorta your call as to what you want to do...doing the display and what not should be cake for you from within the template.